# Antlr Time-out waiting to connect to the remote parser

Tags: timeout, connection, antlr, grammar, antlrworks

I am using the newest ANTLR.                                                                                                                                                                                            I get this error message while trying to debug this grammar:

```
grammar Grammar;

options {   language = Java;
}

@header {
package parser;
import java.util.HashMap;
import viewmodel.*;
import java.util.List;
}

@members {
/** Map variable name to Integer object holding value */
HashMap memory = new HashMap();
}

prog returns [DiagramNode node]
    :   clas 
        {$node = $clas.node;}
    ;

clas returns [DiagramNode node]
    :VISIBILITY* CLASSORINTERFACE name=NAME '{' classDef '}' NEWLINE
        {$node = $classDef.node;
        $node.setName(name.getText());
        }
    ;

classDef returns [DiagramNode node]
    :{$node = new DiagramNode();    }
    fieldDef ';' NEWLINE?
        {$node.getFields().add($fieldDef.field);}
    ;

fieldDef returns [DiagramField field]
    :{$field = new DiagramField();}
    type=NAME name=NAME ';' NEWLINE? 
        {$field.setType(type.getText());
        $field.setName(name.getText());
        }
    ;


VISIBILITY 
    :   ('public' | 'private' | 'protected');
CLASSORINTERFACE
    :   ('class' | 'inerface');
NAME
    :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9') *;
INT :   '0'..'9'+ ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' {skip();};
WS  :   (' '|'\t')+ {skip();} ;
```

The input is:

```
class Abc {
    Type1 Name1;
    Type2 Name2;
}
```

I am assuming that it's grammar's fault, cause another one was compiling and working fine. Could you point me possible errors?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I see that there are no people here who know anything about ANTLR. Luckily I've figured it out on my own. The cause of the problem was the logic inside the grammar - I don't know what exactly, it could be wrong import, using variables, arguments or returns in a wrong way, or eventually missing package declaration for lexer:

```
@lexer::header{
    package parser;
}
```

Comment: Absolute nonsense! I already told you the problem was likely in your custom code: you just didn't want to listen (and were not particularly grateful _and_ was trying to rush me into answering you!). The absence of a `@lexer::header` was definitely not the problem: let that be clear to anyone reading this Q&A.

Comment: How can you explain the fact that without changing any line in my custom code it started working after changes only in grammar logic?

Comment: I think you're just making it up because you're a spiteful child. The fact that you started your "answer" with _"I see that there are no people here who know anything about ANTLR."_ told me enough. Buh-bye.

Comment: The statement was based on the fact that after couple of days there was no answer in the subject. Hopefully I made it worked on my own. Of course you could take into consideration the fact that there had been kind of answer, but guess what? You deleted it, because I wasn't thankful enough for it. Yeah, I am a child, but your behavior is very mature. Dear Bart Kiers I have no obligation to thank for any useless answer I am getting from you. If it was resolving my problem, I would mark it as an accepted answer. What's more you started offecncing me with no reason (just like a 'spiteful child').

Comment: Correct, you don't _have_ to thank anyone for their time spent on your question. But you know what, it's just common courtesy to do so. Note that I didn't remove my answer because you didn't take the time to say thanks or to accept the answer: I really don't care. The fact you didn't pay attention to what I suggested **and** the fact that you were trying to hurry me into answering you (which you edited out, but still is visible in the history) is why I removed my answer. Just for the record: this accepted answer is **not** the solution to any time-out-problem. Anyone reading this, ... TBC

Comment: ... please create a question of your own, and I or someone else will (try to) help you. Don't mind this non-sense answer.